# realloc() problems with the old size

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, realloc

I want to read a lot of information from a file, so I need a dynamic memory.
This is why I use malloc for my struct in the main.
I wanted to realloc with every new line I get from the file, but he says "realloc(): invalid old size", and does not even realloc once.

```
typedef struct{
 int anzahl;
 int ANR;
 char MHD[10];
 char Bezeichnung[20];
 char VPE[5];
 float Preis;
 float gesamtpreis;
}Ware; 

int DateiLesen(Ware *Rechnung)
{
FILE *datei_lesen = NULL;
char trennung[] = " :,;\n\0=";
char zeilen_lesen[256] = {0};
char *formatierer = NULL;
int count = 0;

datei_lesen = fopen("artikel.txt","r");
while(fgets(zeilen_lesen,256,datei_lesen))
{
    count++;
}
fclose(datei_lesen);
if(count == 0)
{
    return -1;
}
datei_lesen = fopen("artikel.txt","r");
while(fgets(zeilen_lesen,256,datei_lesen))
{
    fputs(zeilen_lesen,datei_lesen);
    formatierer = strtok(zeilen_lesen,trennung);
    if(atoi(formatierer) >= 100000)
    {
        Rechnung->ANR = atoi(formatierer);
        formatierer = strtok(NULL,trennung);
        strcpy(Rechnung->MHD,formatierer);
        formatierer = strtok(NULL,trennung);
        strcpy(Rechnung->Bezeichnung,formatierer);
        formatierer = strtok(NULL,trennung);
        strcpy(Rechnung->VPE,formatierer);
        formatierer = strtok(NULL,trennung);
        Rechnung->Preis = atoi(formatierer);
        Rechnung =  realloc(Rechnung,1*sizeof(Ware));
        //Rechnung = (Ware*) realloc(Rechnung,1);
        Rechnung++;
    }
}
fclose(datei_lesen);
return 0;
}


int main(void) {
Ware *Rechnung = (Ware*) malloc(sizeof(Ware));
int test = 0;

initialisiere(&Rechnung);
test = DateiLesen(&Rechnung);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: your signature for the `DateiLesen` function doesn't match the parameters that you pass in.  Do you see any compiler warnings? `DateiLesen` says it wants a pointer to i.e. a `*Ware` type, but you have passed in a `**Ware` type.

Comment: StackOverflow does not really require perfect English, or I myself would be pretty lost. But please try a little harder to avoid the impression that you cannot be bothered with punctuation, capitalisation only where appropriate and basic grammar. You will not actually insist that you really think "wanna" is correct, will you? Giving instead the impression that you at least tried will give you better reactions. Also even in code, using English words for identifiers will make your question/code easier to understand for the majority of potential answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you grow an array.

First,

```
Rechnung++;
```

is fine and dandy, but `Rechnung` is no longer a pointer returned by a previous call to `malloc` or `realloc`. So you can neither `realloc` nor `free` it.

Second,

```
Rechnung =  realloc(Rechnung,1*sizeof(Ware));
```

is fine if you want to leave the size of the array always at 1 element no matter what. If you want the size to increase, you need to feed in the new size.

A typical array-growing loop often looks like this:

```
Data *array = NULL; // note it's fine to realloc a NULL
size_t size = 0;
while (fgets(...)) {
    size_t new_size = size + 1;
    Data *new_array = realloc(array, sizeof(Data) * new_size);
    if (new_array == NULL) {
       // report an error, exit, abort, try again, whatever
       // note having a separate `new_array` variable allows you 
       // to retain old data in `array` in the case of `realloc` erroring on you
    } else {
       array = new_array;
       array[size].foo = make_foo();
       array[size].bar = make_bar();
       size = new_size;
    }
}
```

Note you *never* increment `array` because you cannot pass an incremented `array` to `realloc` . You cannot also have something like this:

```
    Data *array = malloc(sizeof(Data));
    Data *current = data;
    while (...) {
        ...
        current->foo = make_foo();
        current->bar = make_bar();
        array = realloc(array, sizeof(Data) * new_size);
        current++;
    }
```

because `realloc` may and will return a pointer different from what it was passed, and `current` will become invalid. So use plain old boring array indexing.